# Copying values of a column which is filled in series to another Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting "#Value!" for the cell which have formula or if the  column is filled in series. I am trying to copy the content from one sheet to the other on some condition of date.

```
Sub TransferDataMacro()

    Sheets("Summary").UsedRange.Cells.Clear
    Sheets("OSS").Range("B2:K2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("B2")

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim i, LastRow As Long, xdate As Date, change As String

    j = 3

    LastRow = Sheets("OSS").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To LastRow

        change = "G" + CStr(i)

        Sheets("OSS").Activate

        xdate = Worksheets("OSS").Range(change)

        If Month(Date) = Month(xdate) And Year(Date) = Year(xdate) Then

            Sheets("OSS").Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "K")).Copy
            Sheets("Summary").Activate
            Sheets("Summary").Range(Cells(j, "B"), Cells(j, "K")).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: edited the question..

Comment: your i is a variant not a long BTW

Comment: its "," there. LastRow is Long

Comment: ^^ My point is that  whilst you can have i as a variant it is neither efficient nor necessary and leaving a variable to be implicitly typed can make debugging more difficult when you suddenly get type mismatch down the line.

Comment: @Prashu `Dim i, LastRow As Long` is equivalent to `Dim i As Variant, LastRow As Long`, not to `Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long`

Comment: ok noted..Please solve my issue of copying data into other sheet. VAlue filled in series is not getting copied. Just need concept of copying the data of a cell which has some formula written like in series it is B2+1 and so on

Comment: What formulas are in the various columns, and are you really trying to copy the formulas to the other worksheet or do you just want to copy the values?

Comment: just values of the cell... getting output of this  "6 Training Testing Life Cycle" as "#VALUE! Training Testing Life Cycle
"

Comment: In that case, don't use copy and paste to copy the formulas - just say `Sheets("Summary").Range(Cells(j, "B"), Cells(j, "K")).Value = Sheets("OSS").Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "K")).Value`

Comment: not worked subscript out of range error

Comment: As I wrote my comment into an answer, I realised that you would need to qualify the unqualified `Cells` properties, but that shouldn't have given a "subscript out of range" error, it should have given a 1004 error.

Comment: It you want to copy values **and** formats, use the `PasteSpecial` method specifying that you want to copy values and then use it again specifying that you want to copy formats.  I don't think you can do both at once, but I don't use that often enough to be sure, and certainly am not confident enough to post an answer.  (I'd have to record a macro while doing it manually and see what code to use.)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to copy values and cell formats you will need to use `PasteSpecial`:

```
Sub TransferDataMacro()
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, xdate As Date
    Dim j As Long

    With Worksheets("OSS")    
        Worksheets("Summary").UsedRange.Cells.Clear
        .Range("B2:K2").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2")

        j = 3
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 3 To LastRow
            xdate = .Cells(i, "G").Value

            If Month(Date) = Month(xdate) And Year(Date) = Year(xdate) Then
                .Cells(i, "B").Resize(1, 10).Copy
                Worksheets("Summary").Cells(j, "B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Worksheets("Summary").Cells(j, "B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Prashu It helps if you tell us which line has the error.

Comment: @Prashu Please don't "accept" the answer until we get it working!

Comment: thanks it worked..to add I lost the borders of table which was being created at time of copy by previous method. By this method I got values of each cel  but table borders gone

Comment: @Prashu Please unaccept the answer then so that I can delete it.  If you want to copy values **and** formats, there is a different way to do things.

Comment: @Prashu OK, I recorded a macro to find out how to do a copy/pastespecial values and formats, and have updated my answer to include that.